# Remove duplicates from a string - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function textremv() {
    var output = document.getElementById("content").value;
    output = output.replace(/\s/g, "") 
    output = output.replace(/-/g, "")
    output = output.replace(/,/g, ", ")
    output = output2
    output2 = Array.from(new Set(output2.split(','))).toString();
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = output;
}
</script>


<textarea rows='5' cols='50' id='content'></textarea>
<input type='button' value='Extract Text' onclick='textremv()'/>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Purpose: Aiming to break down phone numbers to 10 characters by first removing extra spaces, removing dashes, and then adding a space after the comma.

Ex: 555-  555-5555, 555-5555555, 555555-5555 in a textarea would return 5555555555, 5555555555, 5555555555

GOAL: The code above works kind of if I remove **"output = output2."** I was trying to save the "fixes" into a new var. What I want to do is remove duplicates from the output which the code above is removing duplicates prior to the format. So the only return I would get would just be 5555555555 since there are duplicates in that example.

I'm not married to the above code if there's another way in javascript. I did research other questions on here but what I'm finding is they don't really mesh up with the output that I'm using.

EDIT: T.J's answer worked for me. I also made another textarea and added this

```
document.getElementById("content2").innerHTML = output;
```

where content2 is the name of another text area incase anyone else finds this and wants to have an easy copy/paste option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The code above works kind of if I remove "output = output2." I was trying to save the "fixes" into a new var.

That's because `output = output2` replaces the string you just constructed with whatever was originally in `output2`.

I'm not sure where `output2` comes from (it's not declared in your code), so I'm adding a `let` to declare it in the following:

```
var output = document.getElementById("content").value;
let output2 = output.replace(/\s/g, "");
output2 = output2.replace(/-/g, "");
output2 = output2.replace(/,/g, ", ");
output2 = Array.from(new Set(output2.split(','))).toString();
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = output2;
```

Though there's really no need for `output2` at all, and you can combine things a bit:

```
let output = Array.from(
    new Set(
        document.getElementById("content").value
        .replace(/\s|-/g, "")
        .split(',')
    )
).join(", ");
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = output;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped and I figured out how to make it write to another textarea. Thank you TJ